# Is not freeing TMemoryStream causing a memory leak?

Tags: delphi

I am using TWebModule with Apache.  I am having problems with a memory leak.  In the code below is not freeing the **ImageStream** a memory leak?  If I do free it I get an access violation.

```
procedure TWebModule1.WebModule1WebActionItem8Action(Sender: TObject;
    Request: TWebRequest; Response: TWebResponse; var Handled: Boolean);
  var
    RecNo: Integer;
    ImageStream: TmemoryStream;
  begin
    RecNo := StrToInt(Request.QueryFields.Values['RecNo']);
    Master.MoveBy(RecNo - Master.RecNo); // go to right record
    ImageStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
    with TGraphicField.Create(Master) do
    try
      FieldName := 'Graphic';
      SaveToStream(ImageStream)
    finally
      Free
    end;
    ImageStream.Position := 0; // reset ImageStream
    Response.ContentType := 'image/jpg';
    Response.ContentStream := ImageStream;
    Response.SendResponse
  end;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Setting_the_Response_Content):

> If you use the ContentStream property,
>   do not free the stream yourself. The
>   Web response object automatically
>   frees it for you.

Having said that, why involve ImageStream at all?  Why not just use:

```
Response.ContentStream := TMemoryStream.Create
```

and save the image to that stream directly?

Comment: Thanks - I kind of expected that to be the answer.  And I will employ your idea too.  My memory leak must be somewhere else!